# Is there a archive of old man pages? specifically for the features available for grep in early 'ed'

Tags: grep, history, man

This is just a bit of history rummaging... I'd like to know how different today's `grep` is to the original implementation, introduced by Ken Thompson in [ed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29). which evolved to [ex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_%28editor%29), which then became [vi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi)...
I think too, that `emacs` was an evolution of `ed` (with macros)...

Comment: Emacs was an evolution of TECO, not ed. Emacs didn't originate from the unix world but from MIT (which explains why its key bindings aren't aligned with unix, for example `Ctrl+G` and not `Ctrl+C` as the break key).

Comment: Thanks Gilles.. yes, it seems to be `E macs` (not `ed` macs).. 'E' being a Stanford editor whose WYSIWYG feature had impressed Richard Stallman (RS), and the 'MACS' being the macro feature RS added to MIT's TECO.. This info came from wikipedia'a [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs#History) page (a page with 6 `citation needed` alerts in its History section... but they read well :)...

Comment: At one time, I had a full set of printed 1971 Unix manuals, published somewhere on Usenet. They were a *very* interesting read, but they're long lost now (to me, at least). Oh, and Richard Stallman is rms, not RS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could look at the [Manual Page Library](http://man.cat-v.org/), it has some early UNIX manuals...

Comment: Thanks... http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/1/ed ... There is certaily a lot more to grep these days.. but the basic structure hasn't changed

Answer (score 4):

In the [online freebsd man pages](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi) you can select the OS version